# How to calculate the difference between 2 dates, split them dynamically? Python

Tags: python, list, datetime, if-statement, while-loop

I have to write a function which will count a difference in days between 2 dates. If the number of days exceeds 30, then split it in n date ranges and save in list or dict. I have started with the function but cannot finish it. The function has to calculate dynamic values.

For example

```
start_date = '2020-07-01'
end_date = '2020-09-15'


difference = (end_date - start_date).days


dateranges = []
dateranges.append(start_date)


if difference > 30:
    end_date = start_date + dt.timedelta(days=30)
    dateranges.append(end_date)
```

But I do not get how to make it cyclic, when it take each time a new start_date and end_date and calculates the difference between them. For example I always add 30 dys here but it can be that a less number of days has to be added.

Comment: I don't see any function at all? Where do you parse the strings? -> Please add a [mre].

Comment: well I can't I cannot undersand how to put it all in a function

Comment: what about using a loop? once you have a concept how to do the iteration, you can worry about how to put the code in a function.

Comment: "but it can be that a less number of days has to be added" - you need to provide examples and the logic behind your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want list of date ranges, between 2 dates, with maximum difference of 30 days, you can use timedelta to iterate over the range and split accordingly.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def get_range(start_date, end_date, date_diff):
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    
    if abs((end_date - start_date).days) <= date_diff:
        return [datetime.strftime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d"),datetime.strftime(end_date,"%Y-%m-%d")]
    else:
        result=[]
        while 1:
            d3=start_date+timedelta(days=date_diff)
            if d3>=end_date:
                result.append([datetime.strftime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d"),datetime.strftime(end_date,"%Y-%m-%d")])
                break
            else:
                result.append([datetime.strftime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d"),datetime.strftime(d3,"%Y-%m-%d")])
                start_date=d3+timedelta(days=1)
        return result
    
print(get_range('2020-07-01', '2020-09-15',30))
```

**Output**

```
[['2020-07-01', '2020-07-31'], ['2020-08-01', '2020-08-31'], ['2020-09-01', '2020-09-15']]
```

Here I assume, by date range, you mean start and end date like `[start,end]`.

Answer (score 1):

> For example I always add 30 dys here but it can be that a less number
> of days has to be added.

`datetime` library and `timedelta` function takes care of it and increase month if need.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start_date = '2020-07-01'
end_date = '2020-09-15'

def date_difference(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    
    if abs((d2 - d1).days) > 30:
        dates = []
        # if you don't want to include start_date, use range(1, 30) instead.
        for i in range(0, 30):
            dates.append(d1 + timedelta(days=i))
        return dates
    return []
    
print(date_difference(start_date, end_date))
```

### Output:

```sh
[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 2, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 4, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 0, 0),
...
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 30, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
    from datetime import datetime,timedelta
       def split_dates(prev_date,next_date,interval):
           date_ranges = []
           if next_date > prev_date+timedelta(days=30):
               while prev_date <= next_date:
                   prev_date +=  timedelta(days=interval)
                   date_ranges.append(prev_date)
           return date_ranges
```

Comment: Badly indented Python code _doesn't work!_ Also, while code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!